# ¿Cómo insertar un JPasswordfield en una JTable en Java?

Tags: java, java-swing, jtable

Saludos camaradas y buen día.

Estoy tratando de hacer que los datos de mi columna "contraseña" no se vea como un texto legible. ¿Cómo hago para que en vez de que sea "1102882124" se vea como "**********".

[image: Imagen de la interfaz de usuario]

Código

```
private void llenarTablaVendedor(){
  String encabezado[] = {"ID","DNI","Nombres","Apellidos","Teléfono","Estado", "usuario","contraseña"};
  modeloTablaVendedor = new DefaultTableModel(encabezado, 0);
  modeloTablaVendedor.setRowCount(0);
  Object[] filas = new Object[encabezado.length];
  List<EntidadVendedor> lista = vendedor_dao.listar();               

  for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
    filas[0]=lista.get(i).getIdUsuario();
    filas[1]=lista.get(i).getDni();
    filas[2]=lista.get(i).getNombres();
    filas[3]=lista.get(i).getApellidos();
    filas[4]=lista.get(i).getTelefono();
    filas[5]=lista.get(i).getEstado();
    filas[6]=lista.get(i).getUsuario();
    filas[7]=lista.get(i).getClave();
    modeloTablaVendedor.addRow(filas);            
  }

  tabla_vendedor.setModel(modeloTablaVendedor);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

En principio necesitas 3 pasos: Tomar la columna, aplicarle un *cellEditor* (de `JPasswordField`) y después especificar un *cell render* de tipo `JPasswordField`.

```
private void llenarTablaVendedor() {
  //...

  tabla_vendedor.setModel(modeloTablaVendedor);
  TableColumn tc=tabla_vendedor.getColumnModel().getColumn(7);//Paso 1
  tc.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(new JPasswordField()));//Paso 2
  ClaveRender cr=new ClaveRender();
  tc.setCellRenderer(cr);//paso 3
}
```

La clase que va a permitir que se haga un *renderer* de `JPasswordField`:

```
class ClaveRender extends JPasswordField implements TableCellRenderer {
  @Override
  public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable t,Object o,boolean sel,boolean focus,
      int row,int col) {
    setText((String)t.getValueAt(row,col));
    setBorder(null);
    return this;
  }
}
```

Lo anterior muestra algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Efectivamente. Gracias camarada.